# javascript simple Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi for the below javascript I want a regex which will replace all instances of left square bracket with \Left square bracket ,right square bracket with \ plus right square bracket or full stop with a \ dot

```
<script type="text/javascript" type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var someId = '#Something[0].AnotherSelected[5].Validator';

            alert(s);
        });

    </script>
```

Comment: Your description of what you want doesn't match your example. You don't want to replace those characters with double slash, you want to prefix them with double slash.

Comment: your right barmar i have updated question to match. I want a regex which will replace all instances of left square bracket with \\Left square bracket ,right square bracket with \\ right square bracket or full stop with a \\ dot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var str = 'something[.something]].something[';
console.log(str.replace(/[\[\]\.]/g, '\\\\'));
```

Outputs

```
something\\\\something\\\\\\something\\';
```

[EDIT - based on the OP's comment below:

```
console.log(str.replace(/[\[\]\.]/g, function($0) { return '\\\\'+$0; }))
```

Comment: thats close but i want to keep the square brackets but just put a \\ in front of it so i want str= #Something\\[0\\].AnotherSelected\\[5\\]\\.Validator

Answer (score 2):

First we need a regular expression that matches '[',']' and '.' globally.
This regular expression looks like this:

```
 /(\[|\]|\.)/g
```

Then we replace each occurence with \\ concatenated with matched substring [$&](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#section_5)

```
var someId  = "#Something[0].AnotherSelected[5].Validator";
var newstr  = someId.replace(/(\[|\]|\.)/g, "\\\\$&")
alert(newstr)​
```

The output is

```
 #Something\\[0\\]\\.AnotherSelected\\[5\\]\\.Validator
```

You can test it on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EDDBT/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
someId = someId.replace(/\[/g, "\\\\[").replace(/\./g, "\\\\.");
```

Comment: That's an invalid regular expression.

Comment: of course, but stackoverflow didn't display all my characters. So I've edited it.

Answer (score 0):

```
someId = someId.replace(/[][.]/g, '\\\\$&');
```